# Can Nunit 3.0 know how many tests are selected to execute before they get executed?

Tags: c#, nunit-3.0

Is it possible to determine how many tests have been selected to execute before the test runner executes them? This would be helpful for local testing since our logic generates test configuration for every test suite configuration at a time, having the ability to figure out which tests have been selected to execute could allow me to create logic to only create test data configuration for those tests.

This would be useful when writing tests and testing that they work. Since we only want to generate test data for the selected test.

Right now we have to comment out code to disable it from executing the test data configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you create the test data in your test - or a in a startup step?

Comment: its a bit more involved than that. We are generating everything up front and creating items in the database using docker to host our database. We need to perform an application pool reset before each configured test data can be viewed in the client. Performing App Pool can take up to 2 mins to reconnect to the client. This would make each test take at least 2 mins plus however long the test itself takes. Very inefficient. We have to generate everything up front based on the test suite executing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking this a bit. Your setup can be done with a combination of splitting the setup work between the whole test assembly setup that only runs once, namespace wide setup that runs once before any test in the namespace is run, the constructor for a test fixture, the start of an actual test, etc.

If you are reusing a docker instance and app pool for all the tests then initialize it in the whole assembly setup so that it is only done once. Then each test can just add whatever data it needs before it starts. If some of that data is shared between tests then just setup global flags to indicate what has been done already and if some data a test needs hasn't been setup then just do the incremental additional setup needed before continuing with that test, but this generally isn't required if you organize your tests into namespaces properly and just use the namespace wide setup for fixtures.